# Not able to see swagger in IIS .Net Core

Tags: iis, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently developing Web Api .net core 5.0 with swagger.
I have hosted my application in IIS.I am able to see my Web APi working but my swagger is not responding.

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TestWebApi", Version = "v1" });               
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "Please insert JWT with Bearer into field",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
   {
     new OpenApiSecurityScheme
     {
       Reference = new OpenApiReference
       {
         Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
         Id = "Bearer"
       }
      },
      new string[] { }
    }
            });
        });
```

Also in configure services I have used double dots as mentioned solutions in one of the forums.[GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10514)

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TestWebApi v1") 
                
                );
```

I tried checking the web api as [localapi](http://localhost:8800/TokenApi/swagger) but I am getting 404 error.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked by running the API using Kestrel or IIS Express?

Comment: It is working in localhost. I am able to see swagger while running in VS 2019

Comment: Can you see swagger locally? This problem only appears on iis? Can you post detailed information about 404 error?

Comment: I can see swagger locally. This problem appears in IIS only.

Comment: No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8800/TokenApi/swagger
HTTP ERROR 404.

Comment: What happens if you try full url with index.html i.e. http://localhost:8800/TokenApi/swagger/index.html

Comment: I see Error 404

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Comment: Failed request tracking is a mechanism in Swagger? There is not much mentioned in iis logs.

Comment: You can refer to this link: [Using Failed Request Tracing to Trace Rewrite Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).

Comment: app.UseSwaggerUI was in condition that isDevelopment loop. For this reason it was working in VS 2019 but not in IIS deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

app.UseSwaggerUI was in condition that isDevelopment loop. For this reason it was working in VS 2019 but not in IIS deployment.

Comment: Please, could you point out the file that must be modified? thank you